# What is the proper way to bind a radio button in MVVM / MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm currently binding my radio buttons individually, in other words, I have a `command` for each one, everything works fine but I would like to somehow have only one command where all of them bind.

Here is what I have...

**XAML:**

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1" 
                         Content="RadioButton1"  
                         IsChecked="True"
                         Command="{Binding RadioButton1Command }"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton2" 
                         Content="RadioButton2"  
                         IsChecked="True"
                         Command="{Binding RadioButton2Command }"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    public RelayCommand RadioButton1Command { get; }
    public RelayCommand RadioButton2Command { get; }

    public MyClassConstructorViewModel()
    {
        RadioButton1Command = new RelayCommand(radioButton1Click);
        RadioButton1Command = new RelayCommand(radioButton2Click);
    }


    private void radioButton1Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Radio Button 1 Clicked...");
    }
    private void radioButton2Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Radio Button 2 Clicked...");
    }
```

Is there a way to bind all radio buttons to a single `RelayCommand` and be able to respond accordingly?

Thanks!

Comment: pass some CommandParameter, unique for each RadioButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the name of the `RadioButton`. By the name received in the method, you can your right action.

**XAML**

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1" 
                         Content="RadioButton1"  
                         IsChecked="True"
                         Command="{Binding RadioButtonCommand }" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton2" 
                         Content="RadioButton2"  
                         IsChecked="True"
                         Command="{Binding RadioButtonCommand }" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public RelayCommand<string> RadioButtonCommand { get; }

public MyClassConstructorViewModel()
{
    RadioButtonCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(radioButtonClick);
}


private void radioButtonClick(string name)
{
    if(name == "radioButton1")
        Console.WriteLine("Radio Button 1 Clicked...");
    else if(name == "radioButton2")
        Console.WriteLine("Radio Button 2 Clicked...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: You should however try to find some more general value for the CommandParameter. The name of a view element should not be known in a view model. Note that you could e.g. assign a string like `CommandParameter="1"`.

Comment: @Clemens if the OP want, he can bind the name of the ``RadioButton`` from the ViewModel

Comment: That's not necessary. Just assign *something unique* to CommandParameter.

Comment: @Clemens - How can I set a unique string in the `CommandParameter`? I tried, `CommandParameter="{Binding Path="SomeString"}"` and `CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SomeString}"` but I couldn't capture the value in the ViewModel.

Comment: That Binding requires a property `SomeString` in the view model.

Comment: @fs_tigre you can simply set ``CommandParameter`` by a literal string, like ``CommandParameter``=1

Comment: `CommandParameter="UniqueString"` did the trick, thanks a lot!